# Stripe Form Returns Missing Param

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

My Stripe code is not generating a token to be sent to the server-side code to charge a user, instead it returns:

```
Missing required param: number.
```

I've read through my code countless times, read through Stripe documentation, etc. The only error returned in the console is the 400 request error from Stripe because of the "missing param", even though it exists AND uses data-stripe.

Snippet of the form:

```
<input type="text" data-stripe="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Card Number">
```

The JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_6G4sPCuttf9bYhMhs0xM3JEo');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var $form = $('#payment-form');
$form.submit(function(event) {
// Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
$form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

// Request a token from Stripe:
Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

// Prevent the form from being submitted:
return false;
});
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
// Grab the form:
var $form = $('#payment-form');

if (response.error) { // Problem!

// Show the errors on the form:
$form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
$form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

 } else { // Token was created!

// Get the token ID:
var token = response.id;

// Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

// Submit the form:
$form.get(0).submit();
}
};
```

Comment: In console, check what data is parsing in `post`, when It fired an ajax for token

Comment: Are you sure you've included jQuery, and `$form` does contain the `<form>` element with the various `data-stripe="..."` fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can not generate token just from Card Number. You need to pass following data as well.

1. card number
2. cvc
3. exp_month
4. exp_year

Your form should capture all these details from user.

```
<form action="/your-charge-code" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>
```